# How do I get page attributes and its values in code in Blazor Server side

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor 6

I have two types of authorization attributes on page
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "IsAdmin")]
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "AdminRole,UserRole")]

How can check in code is Authorize attributed is placed on page and get its type (Policy or Roles) and get its value ("IsAdmin" or "AdminRole,UserRole")

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AuthorizeAttribute authorizeAttribute = 
           Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType(), 
           typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)) as AuthorizeAttribute;
    }
```